# Solr Read Timeout (only in production environment)

Tags: java, solr, timeout, solrj

I am working with a Java application that uses *SolrJ* to index documents to a Solr server.

In my local test environment, I run a local Solr instance on a Tomcat server on my windows xp box.  When I run the Java app from a different Windows box, the indexing completes successfully and the Solr log files look normal.

However, running the same Java application deployed on linux webserver communicating to another linux webserver running Solr, I receive "read timed out" messages after every solr update command:

> Jul 14, 2011 3:12:31 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute INFO: []
>
> webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=1} status=400
>   QTime=20020  Jul 14, 2011 3:12:51 AM
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish INFO: {} 0
>   20021 Jul 14, 2011 3:12:51 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:72)     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
>     at...
>
> Caused by:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   Read timed out

Any idea why this might be happening?  My suspicion is that something is closing these connections after they are initiated (e.g. web filtering software, firewall...), but the network admins at my workplace say that no traffic is being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Is it getting timedout only with updates or even with querying?

Check the server settings on the linux server machine whether it has very less timeout value.

Comment: solrconfig.xml has commit timeout values set to 50 secs, which should be way more than enough.  I could be mistaken, but I don't think any other timeout values need to be set.

Comment: There are also solrj timeouts assigned to the underlying httpclient library